# Track WPF message box text and confirmation box 'Yes' button in Coded UI testing

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests, messagebox

How can we track the message from the WPF message box instead of web, also how to click 'Yes' button of a confirmation message box in Coded UI Testing programmatically?

I tried the following but it's not working:

for message box:

```
    UITestControl msgBox = new UITestControl(App);
    msgBox.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
    msgBox.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Text");
    msgBox.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "Test cases added successfully.");
    bool isExist = msgBox.Exists;
    Assert.IsTrue(isExist);
```

for confirmation dialogue 'Yes' button:

```
    UITestControl btnYes = new UITestControl(App);
    btnYes.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
    btnYes.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Button");
    btnYes.SearchProperties.Add("AutomationId", "Yes");
    Mouse.Click(btnYes);
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I used recording capability of CodedUI and got my answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "**record**" facility to get all the details:

[Record actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx#VerifyingCodeUsingCUITCreate)

Thanks!